# Linkage Error using Jep and Java17 on Arch

Tags: python, java, interpreter, linkageerror, jepp

I tried to install jep on a virtual environment with pip but when trying to launch jep interpreter I got:

```
Error: LinkageError when loading the jep.Run main class
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libnio.so: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libnio.so: undefined symbol: reuseport_available
```

When I use ldd I get this:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff1003a000)
    libjava.so => /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libjava.so (0x000073c445d41000)
    libnet.so => /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libnet.so (0x000073c445d29000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x000073c445b1a000)
    libjvm.so => /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/server/libjvm.so (0x000073c444600000)
    /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000073c445d7e000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x000073c444200000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x000073c445a2d000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x000073c445a08000)
```

So everything seems find but still I got this error.

I tried to uninstall reinstall jep, openjdk 17 and plenty of other stuff.
I realize at the begining that libnet.so was not found by libnio.so.
I fix this by adding libnet.so to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.
Still got the error. Start to despair. Any advice ?